# UART sending string VS CharByChar

Tags: putty, serial-port

I am working on an embedded device with an UART connection. Via putty I send commands to that device using ASCII chars. When i send the chars one by one - pressing them manually- (default putty configuration) the device acknowledges the command, But when i enter the whole string and send it all on ENTER press (a different putty option) the device will not recognize the command.

I am sniffing the UART line and in both cases the same chars are detected on the line, on both configuration.

Fix?What may be causing this? Is it a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

Embedded devices often have limited processing power and it is quite usual for some to be unable to process serial input at maximum baud rate without some artificial delay.

If your device implements some handshaking (hardware or XON/XOFF) you need to enable the corresponding options in putty, if not you are stuck with the need for some delay.